# UIPopoverController do not dismiss anymore by tapping outside on ios 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've just updated to the new XCode 6.3 with ios sdk 8.3 and my project (working perfectly on 8.1 and 8.2) seems to have some issue with the PopoverController.

Usually when the popover comes out should be dismissed by touching outside the bounds of the popover (by default); but with in my case **the same code** in iOS 8.2 and 8.1 works perfectly meanwhile it doesn't work on 8.3.

This is the code I used:

```
-(void)showFilter:(id)sender{
if (!filterController)
    filterController = [NodeFilterTableViewController nodeFilterController];
[filterController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
[filterController.popoverPresentationController setBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem];
[self presentViewController:filterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Just to recap the question: The popover is shown correctly by tapping on the button meanwhile is not dismissed by touching outside the boundaries (only if the program is run on iOS 8.3).

Is it changed something in iOS 8.3 about popovercontrollers? I've checked [in Apple iOS diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS83APIDiffs/frameworks/UIKit.html) but I didn't find anything.

UPDATE:

Here I add the implementation of the filterPopover (only method useful for the question):

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
  if (!_filterSetting) _filterSetting = [NSMutableDictionary new];
  [self setModalInPopover:NO];

  }
```

Since the content of the popover has a separate storyboard I use this method for create an instance of it

```
  +(instancetype)nodeFilterController{
     return [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NodeFilterStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NodeFilterController"];
  }
```

Other delegate methods:

```
 -(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion{
     [self.delegate nodeFilterController:self didDismissWithFilters:_filterSetting];
 }

 -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
     [self.delegate nodeFilterController:self didDismissWithFilters:_filterSetting];
 }
```

As I said keep in mind that everything works perfectly on iOS 8/8.1/8.2 **not** 8.3

Comment: Check your `filterController` settings. It sounds like its `modalInPopover` might be switched on. In any case the source of the problem is likely in code / settings you are not showing here.

Comment: matt I added some implementation code of the popover. Maybe it could be useful.

Comment: Are you presenting a view controller inside the popover view controller? The behavior for this has changed in iOS 8.3 (to match the behavior in iOS 7 and before), to be `modalInPopover` automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out the problem.

I still don't know why (because in iOS < 8.3 perfectly works) but the problem was that the view that I tried to show in the popover was not embedded in a navigation controller.

If you put everything inside a navigation controller it perfectly works!

This is the code now:

```
    if (!filterController){
    filterController = [NodeFilterTableViewController nodeFilterController];
    [filterController setDelegate:self];
}
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:filterController];
[navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
[navController.popoverPresentationController setBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem];

[filterController setColorManager:_colorManager];
[filterController setFilterSetting:_filterSetting]; // Setup the precedent active filter if any
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```